# Postgres Table partitioning with non-time-series data

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I recently came across SQL table partitioning and wondered if it fits my use-case.

Most of the online examples use time-series data as an example because as time-series most likely have huge amount of data. But what are other good use-cases?

In one application I have projects and almost every other table refers to a project. One table contains ca. 10000 rows per project (in one deployment I have about 400 projects -> around 4000000 rows). Would I see significant performance benefits in queries and joins (tables are often joined on project basis) if I partition these tables by project ID? Is it worth the additional database management/maintenance?

Comment: Unlikely, 4 million records is not a lot of data. And most likely the project-id will be indexed, right?

Comment: yes, of course it is indexed. thanks for the response